# How can I mask a pandas dataframe column in logging output?

Tags: python, pandas, security, logging

I am having to log some pandas dataframe outputs that contain sensitive information. I would rather not have this info in the logs or print in the terminal.

I normally write a little function that can take a string and mask it with a regex, but I am having trouble doing that with a dataframe. Is there anyway to mask a column(s) of sensitive info in a data frame just for logging? The method I have tried below changes the dataframe, making the column unusable down the line.

```py
def hide_by_pd_df_columns(dataframe,columns,replacement=None):
    '''hides/replaces a pandas dataframe column with a replacement'''
    for column in columns:
        replacement = '*****' if replacement is None else replacement
        dataframe[column] = replacement
    return dataframe
```

What I want to happen is the ***** mask to only exist in logging and not in the rest of the operations.

Comment: Only call that function when you're logging, and for everything else, just use the original dataframe.

Comment: Thanks @Ricky Kim I tried that. I also tried creating a new 'display only' variable form the original data frame and then calling the function on that. For some reason, if I call the function on the dataframe at any point in the code, it changes the dataframe everywhere, even in places where I print or log BEFORE I call it.

Comment: Make sure you called [df.copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) when making 'display only' variable

Comment: geez. That was it! Thank you! Make it an answer and I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to [df.copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) the dataframe if you want to leave the original df as is:

```
def hide_by_pd_df_columns(dataframe,columns,replacement=None):
    '''hides/replaces a pandas dataframe column with a replacement'''
    df=dataframe.copy()
    for column in columns:
        replacement = '*****' if replacement is None else replacement
        df[column] = replacement
    return df
```